# Could the problem of overfishing be solved by throwing fertilized fish eggs at the right place and deepness into the sea?

Tags: marine-biology, ichthyology, environment, ecosystem

I hear sometimes about over fishing and I wonder if the following idea could help to solve the problem.

My idea is to throw fertilized fish eggs at the right place and deepness into the sea. These eggs would then grow by themselves and be the fish to catch sometimes later on.
Instead of the fertilized fish eggs a few days old fish could be used. This should increase the chance of survival by a multitude.

My question is: Could it be done?

In case the answer is yes the next question would be how could it be achieved?

In case the answer is no I am curious: Why would it not work?

Just to be on the save side. The idea is meant to produce more "baby" fish. The "baby" fish should grow in its natural way. Just as if the "baby" fish would have been born in the natural way.
The person putting the eggs into the sea would not be the owner of the grown fish. No monitoring of the way from "baby" fish to grown fish would be done. Anybody could catch the grown fish. Just as it is now the case for natural born fish.

I am looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Apparently it works better with young fish ( fingerlings ) rather than eggs . Fingerling stocking is very widely used.

Comment: Please read the [Tour] to find out what kind of questions are acceptable here. Floating ideas that are only answerable by subjective opinions are not.

Comment: Most fish produce extremely large numbers of eggs anyway.  (Google says tuna can produce 10 million eggs/year!)  Most are, of course, eaten by something before they grow to maturity.

Comment: and where do you get enough fertilized eggs on a renewable basis?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not a forum or tutorial service; it is a Q&A site where *specific* questions relating to biology get *specific* answers. Thank you for taking the [tour], but please carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a lot more complex than simple *yes* or *no*: it depends on the environment, the type of fish in question, the aspects of fishing, etc. Just to list a few points:

- availability of food, shelter and other resources necessary for the eggs to grow - I suppose that this was implied by the phrase *at the right place and deepness into the sea*, but it is more complicated than it seems.
- the preferences of predators/parasites relevant to this species of fish: do they prey on the eggs, the babies or the grown-up individuals?
- the competition for resources with other similar species of fish
- the life history strategy of the species: are they investing in the massive reproduction with high mortality rate of the young? or do the specimen produce relatively small offspring, but live for many years? Do the parents care for their young?
- is this more economically efficient than enforcing fishing quotas? How soon these fish become big enough to be of practical interest for fisheries? Do we expect them to reproduce naturally?

These are all questions that may be answered by conservation ecologists, familiar with the particular kind of fish, environment and the economic situation. But there is no *one-fits-all-sizes* answer.

---

**References**
L. Rockwood, [Introduction to Population Ecology](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Introduction+to+Population+Ecology%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118947579)

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, there's an easy answer to this one: "No!" As Roger points out, there are many complicating factors implicit in your question, but I can't think of any fish species off the top of my head where we could do anything similar to your solution that'd be successful. Consider, for example, Chinook salmon on the west coast of N America. We've been trying to supplement wild populations for decades by releasing juveniles that were spawned and raised to varying ages in hatcheries. There's a legitimate argument to made that this has been successful in that the fisheries for several runs are largely supplied by hatchery-produced fish, but this has come at multiple, complex costs (eg loss of genetic diversity). Perhaps more importantly, many if not most of these runs are still threatened, less due to over-fishing (US fisheries are heavily regulated) than to the loss of spawning habitat and climate change. Ultimately, the "answer" to your question (I'd say) is that the biological and ecological complexities of what you propose are far more than what we can over-come given our state of knowledge and our resources for most species. There are definitely on-going efforts to use hatcheries to supplement or restore wild populations, some of which have had a measure of success, but this is just one (expensive and difficult) tool we can use to address 'over-fishing'. By far the easiest solution (though not without consequences) is to regulate those fisheries--essentially, restrict the quantity of fish caught.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and go through the [help] starting with [answer] and [ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this was not a good question for this site since it is soliciting opinions and discussion. It is also multiple questions rather than a single one. From [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* Answering such questions encourages more inappropriate posts so please delete your post. Thanks.